De-allocating a StringHashMap in Zig
See this question for context.
I am just not figuring out how to de-allocate this:
var groupedFiles = std.StringHashMap([][]const u8).init(allocator);
    defer {
        var values = groupedFiles.valueIterator();
        while (values.next()) |value| {
            allocator.free(value.*);
        }

        var keys = groupedFiles.keyIterator();
        while (keys.next()) |key| {
            allocator.free(key.*);
        }

        groupedFiles.clearAndFree();
        
        // var it = groupedFiles.iterator();
        // while (it.next()) |entry| {
        //     for (entry.value_ptr.*) |file| {
        //         allocator.free(file);
        //     }
        //     // allocator.free(entry.value_ptr.*);
        //     allocator.free(entry.key_ptr.*);
        // }
        groupedFiles.deinit();
    }

For an arrayList, the following code worked fine:
var groupedFiles = std.ArrayList(fileStruct).init(allocator);
    defer {
        for (groupedFiles.items) |group| {
            for (group.files) |file| {
                allocator.free(file);
            }
            allocator.free(group.files);
            allocator.free(group.baseName);
        }
        groupedFiles.deinit();
    }


Your commented out code looks correct to me. Why didn't it work for you?
